# Edit City, State, or Zip combo field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a combination field in a form that allows City, State or Zip. Once keyed, I need to parse out this data into its respective field. Just to be clear, the user should enter EITHER a city and state, or a zip code. My project head would like a user to be able to enter city and state either with or without the comma.

So far, I have this:

```
            searchCity = '';
            searchState = '';
            searchZipCode = '';
            searchValue = $('#branchSearchByCityStateZip').val();

            if (parseInt(searchValue, 10)) {
                searchZipCode = searchValue.substring(0,5);
            } else if (searchValue.search(',') != -1) {
                searchArray = searchValue.split(',');
                searchCity = searchArray[0].trim();
                searchState = searchArray[1].trim();
            } else if (searchValue.search(' ') != -1) {
                searchArray = searchValue.split(' ');
                searchCity = searchArray[0].trim();
                searchState = searchArray[1].trim();
            } else {
                $('#branchSearchModal div.branchSearchError').text('*Please enter a City, St or a Zip code').show();
            }

            if (searchState != '' && searchState.length != 2) {
                $('#branchSearchModal div.branchSearchError').text('*Please enter state abbreviation').show();
                searchCity = '';
                searchState = '';
            }

            // If user pressed submit but didn't key anything, just close the modal
            if (searchCity == '' && searchState == '' && searchZipCode == '') {
                $('#branchSearchModal div.branchSearchError').show();
            } else {
                // Form is good, submit it!
            }
```

This seems to work pretty well, expect if the user enters a city with space and then does not subsequently use a comma before the state. "San Francisco CA" parses out to searchCity=San and searchState=Francisco, then fails in the state length validator.

Any thoughts on how to deal with cities that are more than 1 word?

Comment: Where is the HTML and why not just have multiple fields to enter this data into in the first place?

Comment: The HTML is just a simple modal with one text input field. And agreed, I would like this to be 3 fields but the project manager wants one field.

Comment: I think you should convey this specific scenario to your PM, see what ideas he/she can come up with. personally I can't think of a way of having the input *tell* if the user is still writing a part of the city's name or already began typing the state's. you'd need to take all possible cities and states into consideration to compare! not pretty

Answer (score 1):

If you specify to enter the abbreviated state, you could start at the end and find the first space moving forward in the search phrase to get the state. That only works since there are no spaces in the abbreviated names though. This method would work for "New York NY" but break for "New York New York"